# Create a request in apex, need help in using Map or List

Tags: apex, json, callout

This is my request body

```
     {
 "query":  {
    "operator": "AND",
    "value": [
      {
        "field": "custom_attributes.social_network",
        "operator": "=",
        "value": "facebook"
      }, 
      {
        "field": "custom_attributes.social_network",
        "operator": "=",
        "value": "twitter"
      },
      {
        "field": "custom_attributes.social_network",
        "operator": "=",
        "value": "instagram"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
.
.
.
req.setBody(jsonBody);
```

How do I set the above string in jsonBody, I am new to apex and this is very hard, getting so many errors, not sure to use Map or List or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main approaches you can take to build JSON (plus a 4th one that should not be used in general, only as a last resort, because it is overly verbose and prone to semantic errors).

#### Approach #1: Simple strings

Just make the string directly, and append to it as needed

e.g.
`String myJSON = '{"key":"value", "otherKey":["a","b","c"]}';`

Simple, but hard to manage payloads of even a moderate size.

#### Approach #2: Using `Map<String, Object>` or `List<Object>`

Apex has a `JSON` class, which provides several methods like `JSON.serialize()`

`JSON.serialize()` can take just about anything. A Map or a List (depending on whether your outermost JSON entity is an *Object* or an *Array*) is a fine choice for serializing, especially if you're sending data but not expecting to get and/or use the response.

This approach is also *the* way to handle dealing with things that are invalid identifiers in Apex (e.g. `insert` (being a reserved keyword), `_privateProperty`, `1MoreTime`).

One thing to note that trips up newcomers is the difference between `new Map<String, Object>();` and `new Map<String, Object>{};` (and similarly for Lists and Sets). Using parenthesis means you're calling the constructor of the `Map` type. Using curly braces is how we say that we're *initializing* the Map. When you're trying to make JSON, you want to use the curly braces.

When we initialize a map, we can provide the data we want the map to hold. Otherwise, it'd be a lot of lines of `myMap.put()`. Either way would work in the end, but generally speaking the less typing we have to do, the better.

e.g.

```java
// You would get errors if you tried to use () instead of {}
Map<String, Object> myJSONMap = new Map<String, Object>{
    // This indentation is optional, but helps keep things easy to visually digest
    // Strings in Apex (and we're still in Apex land here) always use single quotes
    'query' => new Map<String, Object>{
         // Each new nested object in your target JSON = another layer of Map<String, Object>
        'operator' => 'AND',
        'value' => new List<Object>{
            // JSON arrays = Apex Lists
            new Map<String, Object>{
                'field' => 'custom_attributes.social_network',
                'operator' => '=',
                'value' => 'facebook'
            },
            // and so on, the final element in a Map, List, or Set is not followed by a comma
        }
    }
};

// You then pass this to JSON.serialize() directly
System.debug(JSON.serialize(myJSONMap));
```

#### Approach #3: Creating (and using) dedicated de/serialization classes

This is the most Object-Oriented approach.

You define Apex class(es) (and/or inner classes in an existing Apex class) that represent the same structure as your target JSON. You then create an instance of the class(es) and populate the data through dot-notation, the constructor(s), or methods.

This is more or less what you get if you use a tool like [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com) (no affiliation).

The upside is that this is probably the easiest way to work with JSON *when you're deserializing*. The downside is that you may need to write unit tests to be able to deploy such classes.

e.g.

```java
public class MyJSON {
    // Variable names will become JSON attribute keys
    Filter query;

    // Classes can be declared inside of a top-level class (only 1 level deep)
    // These are what we call "inner classes"
    public class Filter {
        String operator;
        List<FilterValue> value;
    }

    public class FilterValue {
        public String field;
        public String operator;
        public String value;
    }
}
```

which you would use like

```java
MyJSON data = new MyJSON();
// Inner classes are referenced as <outer class name>.<inner class name>
data.query = new MyJSON.Filter();
data.query.operation = 'AND';
data.query.value = new List<MyJSON.FilterValue>();

MyJSON.FilterValue actualData = new MyJSON.FilterValue();
actualData.operation = '=';

data.query.value.add(actualData);

System.debug(JSON.serialize(data));
```

#### The other one

`JSONGenerator` does exist, but you shouldn't use it unless you know for certain that you must.